# Laravel 5.4 route group and resource mess up the parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

This resource definition is good:

```
Route::resource('servers', 'ServerController');
```

Gives:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                   | Name            | Action                                        | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers               | servers.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | servers               | servers.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/create        | servers.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/{server}      | servers.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | servers/{server}      | servers.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | servers/{server}      | servers.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/{server}/edit | servers.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

But I need to wrap it into a group with prefix like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'servers'], function()
{
    Route::resource('/', 'ServerController', ['names' => 'servers']);
});
```

And here comes the problem, because of prefix the parameterised routes' parameters are empty:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI             | Name            | Action                                        | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers         | servers.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | servers         | servers.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/create  | servers.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/{}      | servers.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | servers/{}      | servers.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | servers/{}      | servers.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | servers/{}/edit | servers.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

So the `servers/1` goes 404. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: To declare a resource route, you need to pass the resource name, i.e. `servers` to the resource method.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap it into group? From what I can see its already in a group.

Comment: @TheAlpha Yes, but in this case I can't use the prefix. And I've checked the core and there is a `prefixedResource` method so I've hoped it can use the prefix for the name if the resource's name just a `/`. But it seems not. Btw thanks your answer.

Comment: @PankitGami Group is needed because of middleware and namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `parameters` to customize all params in route.
Example:

```
Route::prefix('teams')->group(function () {
  Route::resource('', 'TeamController')->parameters(['' => 'team']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Based on your comments:**

You want to add the namespace and middleware to the resource route. You can achieve this by adding `middleware` and `namespace` key in the third parameter of your resource controller like this.

```
Route::resource('servers', 'ServerController', ['middleware' => 'xyz', 'namespace' => 'xyz']);
```

**EDIT:**

If a namespace is not working you can assign a namespace to the controller.

```
Route::resource('servers', 'Xyz\ServerController', ['middleware' => 'xyz']);
```

Comment: I've checked it and no, the namespace is not working as resource parameter. I've set it and still gives the default namespace: `App\Http\Controllers\ServerController@index`

Comment: @MrRP You can achieve it like this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces

Comment: @MrRP try using "servers" folder in capitals "Servers".
As stated in PSR-4: The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.